# Animated GIF with PHP

Tags: php, jquery-animate, png, gif

I want to create a GIF image of animated pixels with transparent background, which get color from Javascript.
I tried using this:
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3163-PHP-Generate-GIF-animations-from-a-set-of-GIF-images.html
And this: http://www.jeroenvanwissen.nl/weblog/php/howto-generate-animated-gif-with-php
But, I have a problem.
I created this code:

```
<?php
header ('Content-type:image/gif');
include('GIFEncoder.class.php');

// Open the first source image and add the text.
$image = imagecreatefrompng('None.png');
imagesavealpha($image, true);
$color = $_GET["sc"];
$r_bg = hexdec(substr($color,0,2));
$g_bg = hexdec(substr($color,2,2));
$b_bg = hexdec(substr($color,4,2));
$c1 = imagecolorallocate($image, $r_bg, $g_bg, $b_bg);
imagesetpixel($image,36,24,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,36,25,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,36,26,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,37,26,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,38,26,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,38,25,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,38,24,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,37,24,$c1);

// Generate GIF from the $image
// We want to put the binary GIF data into an array to be used later,
//  so we use the output buffer.
ob_start();
imagegif($image);
$frames[]=ob_get_contents();
$framed[]=40;

// Delay in the animation.
ob_end_clean();

// And again..
// Open the first source image and add the text.
$image = imagecreatefrompng('None.png');
imagesavealpha($image, true);
$color = $_GET["sc"];
$r_bg = hexdec(substr($color,0,2));
$g_bg = hexdec(substr($color,2,2));
$b_bg = hexdec(substr($color,4,2));
$c1 = imagecolorallocate($image, $r_bg, $g_bg, $b_bg);
imagesetpixel($image,34,23,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,34,24,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,34,25,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,34,26,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,34,27,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,35,28,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,36,28,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,37,28,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,38,28,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,39,28,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,40,27,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,40,26,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,40,25,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,40,24,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,40,23,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,39,22,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,38,22,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,37,22,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,36,22,$c1);
imagesetpixel($image,35,22,$c1);

// Generate GIF from the $image
// We want to put the binary GIF data into an array to be used later,
//  so we use the output buffer.
ob_start();
imagegif($image);
$frames[]=ob_get_contents();
$framed[]=40;

// Delay in the animation.
ob_end_clean();

// Generate the animated gif and output to screen.
$gif = new GIFEncoder($frames,$framed,0,2,0,0,0,'bin');
echo $gif->GetAnimation();
?>
```

I get a hexadecimal color code, then change it to RGB.
But, I get these errors:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant ERR00 - assumed 'ERR00' in <b>D:\Testing\xampp\htdocs\Test\Test.php</</b> on line <b>75</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant ERR01 - assumed 'ERR01' in <b>D:\Testing\xampp\htdocs\Test\Test.php</</b> on line <b>75</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant ERR02 - assumed 'ERR02' in <b>D:\Testing\xampp\htdocs\Test\Test.php</b> on line <b>75</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant ERR03 - assumed 'ERR03' in <b>D:\Testing\xampp\htdocs\Test\Test.php</b> on line <b>75</b><br />
GIF89a2
```

I don't know that is the problem. :/

Answer (score 0):

Check you GIFEncoder class. there is some variable that undefined. try to check `empty($for_all_vars);`

or check [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/discuss/package/3163/thread/16/) out.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I had this error today. It occurs because there's wrong syntax in that 10+ year old `GIFEncoder` library. Where the `$ERR` array is defined, the quotes around the array keys are missing.

The correct code snippet has to be:

```
var $ERR = Array (
    'ERR00'=>"Does not supported function for only one image!",
    'ERR01'=>"Source is not a GIF image!",
    'ERR02'=>"Unintelligible flag ",
    'ERR03'=>"Does not make animation from animated GIF source",
);
```

*(Note the quotes around ERR00 to ERR03, these are missing in the original file that floats around the web.)*

Hope this helps someone.